# data structure design for multiple search combination

Tags: c++, data-structures

Coding a c++ application to store and display a set of records (the number of records could be in the size of 5000's ).

There is a requirement to search on the records based on some of properties in the record. Let's call these properties as classifications.

There are 7 such classifications and each of the classifications could have different possible unique values that can be populated from all the available records. By creating a set of all unique values within all the records in that classification this becomes possible.

User could select multiple values from these classifications and based on the selections from all the classification, search on the record should happen.

Now the problem=>

Say user selects a value from classification 1 then for this value there could be only some matching records. So it means it should be possible to display only valid values in other classifications that matches the current selection. How to filter out invalid values from other classifications based on current selection.

For Eg: say there are 3 records and in each record has 3 columns.It is searchable on all three columns.

```
Record1=> T1, E1, S1  
Record2=> T2, E2, S2  
Record3=> T3, E1, S2
```

So possible values for each classifications are,

```
Classification1=> T1, T2, T3  
Classification2=> E1, E2, E3  
Classification3=> S1, S2, S3
```

Now say user selects T1/T2 from classification1 and E1 from classification2 for search. It means for classification3 it is enough to display just S1.

What is the right datastruture to efficiently handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

Singly linked list and function "filter", which takes a list and a predicate, will give you result in O(n). It would step through the list item by item, checking the predicate against each item. Without any classifications. Try it, should be fast.

Do you need it faster, then O(n)? There could be some index, as in relational dbs. But think twice, do you really need it that fast? Index needs memory and time to build. Internally it is usually a red-black tree, even if it just stores hashes. You could first scan one index, which would make your search set much more narrow, and then apply filter function to what is left.

But if it is not a study task, I'd stick with just filter, or, in the extreme case, use some in-memory relational db.

Comment: Would want it to be faster than O(n), as the filter dialog would need to refresh for every choice of user don't want to search thru all the records for every user selection. Index on what combination of filters. There are 7 different classifications and each classifications can have different number of possible value. Memory isn't a problem but speed is. Thanks.

Comment: @siva-elango-r And don't forget about debounce. Like in http://rxmarbles.com/#debounce (in case filter values are entered by keyboard)